# CSS Text ellipsis returns first line of every paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to apply ellipsis on a text but it takes first line of all the paragraphs. However, I want the first line of the content only.

The Sample Content

```
While sending message via websocket this code is triggered. However, '+ msg +' does not detect new lines (line breaks) in the message. Every sentence appears in the same line.

Optimize this jquery code so that '+ msg +' can detect new lines.
```

What I am getting

[image]

What I really want

[image]

Here is my CSS code

```
.content .message {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #afb9d7;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="name">Shreyansh Jha </div>
  <div class="message " data-msg="While sending message via websocket this code is triggered. However, '+ msg +' does not detect new lines (line breaks) in the message. Every sentence appears in the same line. <br />
    <br />
    Optimize this jquery code so that '+ msg +' can detect new lines.">While sending message via websocket this code is triggered. However, '+ msg +' does not detect new lines (line breaks) in the message. Every sentence appears in the same line. <br>
    <br>
    Optimize this jquery code so that '+ msg +' can detect new lines.
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve the required output?

Comment: How about changing the height of the div to display only one line?

Comment: Yes, I can try that. Gosh! Such a simple thing. Guess excess burnout prevents you from seeing simple solutions sometimes which you have already implemented in the past 100s of times.

Answer (score 0):

Text ellipsis only applies to the width of a single long paragraph.

So here, you have to remove the `<br />` tag and have to use **\n**, if possible. Otherwise, it will take it as a separate section inside that division/paragraph.

Or else, you can make its height fixed and manage it from a CSS perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One :

```css
.message  {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 350px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="message">
  While sending message via websocket this code is triggered. However, '+ msg +' does not detect new lines   (line breaks) in the message. Every sentence appears in the same line.
  Optimize this jquery code so that '+ msg +' can detect new lines.
</div>
```